# Build faild with an exception

Tags: react-native, dependencies

```
npx react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.1/gradle-7.1.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS F:\Govind_projects\mApp> npx react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
getting this error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'F:\Govind_projects\mApp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.application'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.TestOptions.
         > org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectSet.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
error Failed to install the app.
```

is there any dependency issue or something else please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.